# Spotfire get row

Tags: spotfire

anyone know how to reduce the number of returned results from an information link? Something like this

```
SELECT 
  R1."COLUMN NAME"
  R1."COLUMN NAME 2"
  R1."COLUMN NAME 3"
FROM
   "TABLENAME"
WHERE 
ROWNUM <
    (SELECT COUNT - 500000 
     FROM TABLENAME)
```

Comment: What is the type of the datasource ?

Comment: @János Spengler It would be an Oracle database.

Comment: `SELECT  FIRST_ROWS(10000) 
R1."COLUMN NAME"
  R1."COLUMN NAME 2"
  R1."COLUMN NAME 3"
FROM
   "TABLENAME"`

Comment: Didn't work. 

ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to execute data source query. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Answer (score 0):

In the information designer...

- Double click on your Information Link to bring up the Edit Window
- At the very bottom, click the SQL button
- In the `Modified SQL:` window, add the conditions you want to the WHERE clause

Pay attention to how Spotfire quotes and aliases your statement and follow this design. i.e. (SQL Server example)

FROM
   "Server"."schema"."TABLE" A1
WHERE
   A1."SomeColumn" = "some value"

SQL Server doesn't use double quotes, or even single quotes on table and server names, but you have to in this designer.  Anyway, modify the statement as you need and click OK. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle -

```
SELECT
   E1."EMPNO" AS "EMPNO",
   E1."ENAME" AS "ENAME",
   E1."JOB" AS "JOB"
FROM
   "SCOTT"."EMP" E1
WHERE
**rownum <5**
```

For SQL -

```
SELECT **top 9**
   m1."no" AS "NO",
   m1."name" AS "NAME",
   m1."city" AS "CITY"
FROM
   "emp_Hierarchy"."dbo"."myemp1" m1
WHERE
   <conditions>
```

Comment: Cool. This works. Is there a way to make it more dynamic? Say something where I can get the maximum number of rows and subtract from it?

Comment: This works for Oracle -select * from emp where rownum < (select count(*) from emp) - 9  . Something similar query can be used for sql as well

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for this.